# Passing fixed values next to a collection to an options_for_select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I am trying to pass to my select_tag both fixed values and loop values. I can perfectly write something like :

```
<%= select_tag "", options_for_select(session[:user_hotel_list].collect{ |hotel| [hotel["name"], hotel["id"]] }) %>
```

Here `hotel["name"]` will be the displayed value and `hotel["id"]` the "real value" of the field.

But if I try to add extra fixed values to my options_for_select I dont get the desired output. Let's say I want to add a select with "all hotels" with a value of "all". I would try something like that :

```
<%= select_tag "", options_for_select([["all hotels", "all"], session[:user_hotel_list].collect{ |hotel| [hotel["name"], hotel["id"]] }]) %>
```

But here I would get an array as output for the collection...

How can I correctly add extra fixed data to an options_for_select with a collection in rails ?

EDIT

For example this code :

```
<%= select_tag "dash_select", options_for_select( [["all hotels", "all"], ["other", "value"]] << session[:user_hotel_list].collect{ |hotel| [hotel["name"], hotel["id"]] }) %>
```

outputs this :
[image]

and obviously ["plaze", 31] isnt good !

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to add multiple items? Or is your example with just "All hotels" sufficient. Because in that case you could just do:

```
<%= select_tag "", options_for_select(...), { include_blank: "all hotels" } %>
```

Comment: how about `options_for_select([["all hotels", "all"], ["other", "value"]] << session[:user_hotel_list].collect{ |hotel| [hotel["name"], hotel["id"]] })`

Comment: sry, meant "+" instead of "<<"